# Dynamically fetching all class functions in javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I get an array of all my class`s functions and the functions of the classes it inherits from

for example

```
class Foo extends Bar {
      funcA() {}
}

class Bar {
      funcB() {}
}

const instanceFoo = new Foo();

getClassFunctions(instanceFoo); // should return an array ['funcA', 'funcB'];
```

I made a function that returns the function names of a class but it only works on the class`s own properties

```
const getAllFuncs = (obj) => {
    const proto = Object.getPrototypeOf (obj);
    const names = Object.getOwnPropertyNames (proto);
    return names.filter (name => typeof obj[name] === 'function' && name !== 'constructor');
}
```

Comment: Keep going up the `[[Prototype]]` chain and stop when you hit a built–in object (probably the global Object.prototype object, which has a `[[Prototype]]` of *null*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply loop, going to each prototype, probably stopping when you reach `Object.prototype`. I'd also start with the object itself, not its prototype, since methods can be added during construction:

```
const getAllFuncs = (obj) => {
    // Remember which names we've checked
    const checked = new Set();
    // The function names we'll return
    const funcs = [];
    while (obj && obj !== Object.prototype) {
        for (const name of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj)) {
            if (name !== "constructor" && !checked.has(name)) {
                // Remember we've checked this name
                checked.add(name);
                const value = obj[name];
                if (typeof value === "function") {
                    // Remember this function
                    funcs.push(name);
                }
            }
        }
        // Go up a level
        obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
    }
    return funcs;
};
```

The reason `checked` is separate from `funcs` is that an object could have a property named `foo` with a non-function, but its prototype might also have a `foo` with a function. It's rare, but feasible:

```
class Base {
    foo() {
    }
}
class Sub extends Base {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.foo = 42;
    }
}
const sub = new Sub();
const names = getAllFuncs(sub);
```

`names` wouldn't include `foo` because `sub.foo` is `42`, not a function.